# Java finding all combos in array that add up to specific number

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics

I'm currently working on the following question from a interviewing book:

> You are given a random array of 50 unique integers ranging from 1 to 100 inclusive. Write a method using Java that takes in a positive integer as a parameter and returns an array of all the number combinations that add up to that value.

For example, given an array of integers [3,6,1,9,2,5,12] and being passed the integer value 9, you would return [[3,6],[6,1,2],[9],[3,1,5]].  Order of returning the results in the array does not matter, though you should return unique sets (ie. [6,3] and [3,6] are the same and only one should be returned).  Also, the individual results should be in the order they are found (ie [6,1,2] should be returned, not [1,2,6]).

I've made decent progress on it, but I fear I may solving this the wrong way.

```
import java.util.*;


public class findCombinations {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number;
    int[] list = new int[10];
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    //fill the array
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      number = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
      list[i] = number;
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { //remove duplicates
        if (list[i] == list[j]) {
          i--;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    Arrays.sort(list);

    //test output
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int input = reader.nextInt(); 
    ArrayList<Integer> trimmedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //cut out the numbers that are impossible to use
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i] <= input) {
        trimmedList.add(list[i]);
      }
    }
    //test output
    printList(trimmedList);

    ArrayList<Integer> comboList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Finding combinations...");

    for (int i = 0; i < trimmedList.size(); i++) {
      int current = trimmedList.get(i);
      if (current == input) { System.out.println(current); }
      else if (current < input) {
        comboList.add(current);
        if (isCombo(comboList, input)) {
          printList(comboList);
        }
        else { continue; }
      }
      else { continue; }
    }
  }

  public static boolean isCombo(ArrayList<Integer> list, int input) {
    ArrayList<Integer> combo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i : list)
      sum += i;

    if (sum == input) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
  }

  public static void printList(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      System.out.print(list.get(i));
    }
  }
 }
```

I know this is incomplete but I wanted to ask if anyone had any suggestions or improvements I could make on this? I sorted my list and trimmed out all the integers that won't possibly be used, but now the hard part is finding all the combos.

Comment: The whole exercise is to see if you know how to create all sub-lists of a list.  So, you have not started.

Comment: Please, please, remove `else { continue; }`

Comment: This link will probably help you. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36214/find-all-subsets-of-an-int-array-whose-sums-equal-a-given-target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different approaches to solve this problem, each with their own merits, so I wouldn't worry too much about whether your answer is the 'right' one or not...so long as it actually solves the problem! Also, an interviewer will likely be more interested in your thought-process, and the strategies you use, rather than a 100% perfect solution written in the span of a few minutes on a whiteboard.

Here's a couple of things to consider:

- As you noticed, you can immediately eliminate any integers larger than your target value.
- You're essentially generating arbitrarily-sized subsets of your starting array—so `Set` is likely the most useful data type to work with. `{2, 3}` and `{3, 2}` should be seen as identical when you're generating your response set.
- Integer partitioning is an NP-Complete problem. It's hard. I think you've taken the correct approach of starting with the array, rather than with the target value.
- <del>There are many algorithms for generating combinations of integers from a larger set. Check out this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127856/803925) for a few of them. You can generate `k` sized combinations from your (already-filtered) starting set, for `k` from 1-50.</del>
- Actually...there are more direct ways to get the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of your starting set. Consider the inherent structure of a power set (shown below). By enumerating a few examples, you'll notice a natural recurrence in your strategy for identifying the subsets.

As you're generating these combinations, discard any whose elements don't sum to your target value.

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set]

Image Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a learning exercise, you will benefit most if you can solve this for yourself.  So ...

Hints:

1. Sorting the numbers first is on the right track
2. I would use recursion to iterate the solutions.  Given a partial sum, only numbers less than a certain number are possible candidates to be added to the sum ...
3. Work out the algorithm in your head >before< you start coding it.

---

And I agree with what @nbrooks says on the topic of what the interviewers are looking for.  You need to be able to think ... and explain your thinking to the interviewer ... at the algorithmic level.  That is what will distinguish the excellent candidates from the ordinary ones.

Comment: May be it is a learning exercise on how to use SO when you are in trouble

Answer (score 0):

I realize generating your array of random numbers is not part of the problem statement, but I think your difficulties begin here.

First of all, use a `Set<Integer>` type collection to collect your generated numbers; break when the set reaches the desired size. If generated order is important, use a LinkedHashSet.

```
Set<Integer> origSet = new HashSet<Integer>(); // fill with random numbers
```

At some point, you have a list of numbers for which the order matters. Maintain this list as a `List<Integer>`. The list preserves the order of your original list so that you can produce the number combinations in the right order (i.e., 6 precedes 1, 1 precedes 2).

```
List<Integer> origList = new ArrayList<Integer>(origSet); // use indexOf method to find index of a number
```

You create a second list that is sorted; this list is the one used by your recursion algorithm.

```
List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<Integer>(origList); // sort this
```

You don't need to trim the list because a recursive algorithm will trim any branch with no feasible solution.

A recursive algorithm can generate the combos in fewer lines of code. Reordering takes a few more lines.